# Meteor.js for mobile apps

Tags: mobile, meteor

What is the best way to use meteor.js for making cross platform mobile apps.

All I can think of is copying all of the JS and HTML into a string on the mobile device and load all of that into a webview on startup of the app. This may not be the most elegant way of doing it...

I'd also like to address any issues with offline usage of the app.

Comment: Chet did you have any luck this?

Comment: PhoneGap is the ultimate solution... Also check out Meteorite. I've used jQuery Mobile, Top Coat, Swiper.js -- all useful but have their quirks with Meteor.

Comment: Thanks! How was your experience with the final product? Any concerns/issues using meteor on mobile?

Comment: Meteor's been working great -- there are some nuances when using other frameworks though, especially jquery mobile

Comment: Meteor has moved on since '13. Any new readers check out: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration

Comment: yep! this is an older post. want to put that in an answer and I'll mark it

Answer (score 0):

Best answer I can give here is to load your multiple apps into SQL Server 2012 and then simply have a lightweight proxy to deliver the correct app for the respective device.

Never used Meteor but this was our approach for our jQuery mobile apps.